# Graph API doesn't return user info on GET/page/feed, only post_id, datetime, and message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to request the full info related to a post through the graph API? When I do a GET request facebook responds with the created_time, id, and message only. I've even looked for a way to request the info on a separate request passing in the post id, but it looks like post searches were removed in API v2+. It seems that there should be a way to structure the request that I can ask for specific fields, such as likes, and more importantly the name of the person posting.

```
Graph.get('<Page_id>/feed', function(err, response){
  console.log(response);
});
```

If I include `&field={username || user-id || user}` or any other logical query I get a 400 response. I'm sure it's possible, I'm probably just overlooking something in the docs. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use field expansion to get more fields, the parameter is called "fields", not "field": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#reading